# best practice to disable a class instanciating

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-class, static-methods

I want to create a utils-class that would contain only static members, e.g.

```
class A(object):
  X = 0
  @staticmethod
  def f():
    print X
```

I also want all of it methods to be used without an instance, i.e. I want the user to call `A.f()` rather than `a = A(); a.f()`.

One way is using `@abc.abstractmethod`, e.g.

```
class A(object):
  X = 0
  @abc.abstractmethod
  def __init__(self):
    raise Exception('Should not be created!')
  @staticmethod
  def f():
    print X
```

Second option is not using the abstract, since it implies inheritence, which is not a thing I design fir this class. In this case, I would just raise exception from both `__init__`and`__new__`

What would be the best practice (third option?)

Comment: If your class isn't meant to be instantiated (or subclassed), don't use a class. Your class should really just be a module.

Comment: Why you should do that? The answer depends on the reason. For security: forget it. But if it is just an hint to programmer, things could be done simpler. Remember that people could still include your class in a new class (so composition), which can easily simulate inheritance,

Comment: @Aran-Fey I want it to have private methods and public methods. Should I do that in a module too?

Comment: @CIsForCookies Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are asking about what's the "best practice" and not how to technically do it I can answer you that the best practice is to not do that ;) I never saw such construct before and I believe that it violates two Python "principles":

- We are all adults here.
- The principle of Least Astonishment.

## We are all adults here

> This expression is also used in the object-oriented python literature
>   to explain python's attitudes about private class members, which
>   Python doesn't have.
>
> When you create an instance of some class there is nothing to prevent
>   you from poking around inside and using various internal, private
>   methods that are (a) necessary for the class to function, BUT (b) not
>   intended for direct use/access.
>
> After all, we're all consenting adults here.

from: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html

## The principle of Least Astonishment.

> The principle of least astonishment applies to user interface and
>   software design. A typical formulation of the principle, from 1984,
>   is: "If a necessary feature has a high astonishment factor, it may be
>   necessary to redesign the feature."
>
> More generally, the principle means that a component of a system
>   should behave in a way that most users will expect it to behave; the
>   behavior should not astonish or surprise users.

from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way is to put all those static functions in a module. You have no shared state between those funcs,  why do you have to use a class?